# Preventing ARP spoofing in DMZ

Tags: firewalls, webserver, iptables, arp-spoofing, dmz

Is there any possible way to implement a defence mechanism in a firewall to be able to prevent ARP spoofing in a DMZ. Our DMZ server consist of two webservers and a database (which should be available from the internet)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas Jari's answer correctly states measures against some MITM attacks, ARP spoofing is a specific MITM attack which is not prevented by enabling DHCP snooping or port-security, (which protect against DHCP race and CAM table attacks respectively).

ARP spoofing in particular can be protected against by

- setting static ARP values
- deploying dynamic ARP inspection ([e.g. ARPwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arpwatch)).

Please, also check [this stackoverflow question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58899/mitm-is-impossibile-when-the-gateways-arp-entry-is-set-to-static), which lists different kinds of MITM attacks.

Answer (score 0):

ARP spoofing is a layer 2 attack so harden your network by enabling features like DHCP Snooping and port-security on your switches.